# Inserting data to the database with dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I am working with dynamic text boxes.

I want to add the data that is entered in the text boxes to my database.

My markup:

```
<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
    <input type="text" name="number[]" id="number1" value="15" placeholder="Number 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name1" value="aaaa" placeholder="Name 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" value="10" placeholder="Price 1" /> <br />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
            count++;
            $('#total_item').val(count);
            var html_code = '';
            html_code += '<input type="text" placeholder="Number '+count+'" name="number[]" id="number'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" /><br />';
            html_code += '<input type="text" placeholder="Name '+count+'" name="name[]" id="name'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" /><br />';
            html_code += '<input type="text" placeholder="Price '+count+'" name="price[]" id="price'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" /><br />';
            html_code += '<button type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button><br />';
        });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button>
</form>
```

Which results in the following document fragment:

```
<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
    <input type="text" name="number[]" id="number1" value="15" placeholder="Number 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name1" value="aaaa" placeholder="Name 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" value="10" placeholder="Price 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="number[]" id="number2" value="12" placeholder="Number 2" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name2" value="bbbb" placeholder="Name 2" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price2" value="15" placeholder="Price 2" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="number[]" id="number3" value="38" placeholder="Number 3" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name3" value="cccc" placeholder="Name 3" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price3" value="29" placeholder="Price 3" /> <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button>
</form>
```

When submitting the form I want to add the following data to the database:

```
| session_id  |  number  |   name   |   price  |
|-------------|----------|----------|----------|
|      1      |    15    |   aaaa   |    10    |
|      1      |    12    |   bbbb   |    15    |
|      1      |    38    |   cccc   |    29    |
```

In my PHP code I am using the following to define the text boxes:

```
foreach($_POST['number'] as $i => $item) {
```

When I execute the script I only get the data of the first three textboxes. I get in my database:

```
| session_id  |  number  |   name   |   price  |
|-------------|----------|----------|----------|
|      1      |    15    |   aaaa   |    10    |
```

After weeks of doing research I have discovered that there is something wrong with the JavaScript part of the code. When I send the data with the text boxes in the second example I get the result I want. When I use JavaScript to create the dynamic text boxes the PHP script will only post the first row (that is not created with JavaScript) to the database.

What is wrong with my script?

Here is the script I am using to add data to my database:

```
<?php
    $correct = true;
    $_SESSION['session_id'];
    $number = $_POST['number'] ;
    $name = $_POST['name'] ;
    $price = $_POST['price'] ;
    if($correct){
        foreach($_POST['number'] as $i => $item) {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');
            $query= "INSERT INTO products(session_id, number, name, price) VALUES (:session_id, :number, :name, :price)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $exec = $stmt->execute(array(
                ':session_id' => $_SESSION['session_id'],
                ':number' => $_POST["number"][$i],
                ':name' => $_POST["name"][$i],
                ':price' => $_POST["price"][$i]
            ));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: ../error.php');
    }
?>
```

Result of `var_dump` on `$_POST['number']`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "15" }
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the prices fields have `name="name[]`?

Comment: Can you please share dump_var of the `$_POST['number']` before the foreach loop?

Comment: I have modified the script.

Comment: When I do a var_dump on $_POST['number'] I get: array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "15" }

Comment: That `var_dump` output definitely doesn't look right. How many `<form>` tags do you have? Is this just submitting normally, ie not via AJAX?

Comment: I have updated my question with:

<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
.................
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button>
</form>

i don't use ajax!

Comment: I copied your code in my test file and it worked, see my var_dump:
   array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "15" [1]=> string(2) "12" [2]=> string(2) "38" }

Comment: I tried it again. I still get `array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "15" }`. What can be the reason you get the correct response?

Comment: is it really $stmt3 ?

Comment: i have modified the variable name!

Comment: Your JS code doesn't include the part which adds the HTML to the document. Can you show that please.

Comment: I am updating it with `$('#response').append(html_code);`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that all your fields in the form have the same name, even though they are supposed to be arrays, you're not really allowing for multiple rows.

The easiest (not necessarily the optimal) way is to make some tweaks

Change your form element names to

```
variable[$i][number]
variable[$i][name]
variable[$i][price]
```

and make sure your form changes the value for `$i` on each row, so that your form becomes:

```
<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
<input type="text" name="variable[0][number]" id="number1" value="15" placeholder="Number 1" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="variable[0][name]" id="name1" value="aaaa" placeholder="Name 1" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="variable[0][price]" id="price1" value="10" placeholder="Price 1" /> <br />

<input type="text" name="variable[1][number]" id="number1" value="15" placeholder="Number 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="variable[1][name]" id="name1" value="aaaa" placeholder="Name 1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="variable[1][price]" id="price1" value="10" placeholder="Price 1" /> <br />
```

and so on...
Then, alter your form processing to iterate over `$variable`:

```
foreach($variable as $var)
{
   $number = $var['number'];
   $name = $var['name'];
   $price = $var['price'];

   // do whatever it is you do with the variables and then loop to the next row
}
```

that's it!
Like I said, this is not necessarily the best way to accomplish your goal, but it is by far the easiest

Comment: Are you sure that `name="variable[0][number]"` will work with `$var['number'];`? When I run the script (send.php) I get a `HTTP ERROR 500` error because the variables are not correct

Comment: I have discovered that there is something wrong with the Javascript part in my code. So I have updated my question. Can you look at it?

Comment: Yes, the above is correct. It's exactly how I do it... I didn't provide the full code though as it is meant to be a guidance, which is probably the cause for the 500 error you're getting if you just copied-pasted the above. You need to read `$_POST['variable']` into a variable which you then later iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your form fields with the array names, but in order to post your data to the database, you will need to iterate through the array.

So your receiving page should collected all the form data in a $_POST variable, and then you can parse the posted values as $_POST['number'] and iterate through the array using a for-each loop.

```
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $value) {
     // do something with array value
    echo "{$key} => {$value} ";

    print_r($_POST['price']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont inject pure html but play with DOM.

```
<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button><br />
</form>

<script>
function newInput(type, value, count){
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.type = 'text';
    newInput.name = type+'[]';
    newInput.id = type+count;
    newInput.value = value;
    newInput.placeholder = type+' '+count; // <--you probably want to camelize this
    return newInput;
}

function addRow(number, name, price, count, target){
    target.appendChild(newInput('number', number, count));
    target.appendChild(newInput('name', name, count));
    target.appendChild(newInput('price', price, count));
    target.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // <-- create any element
}

var myForm = document.getElementById('reaction');
var count = 0;
addRow(111, 'one', 1, ++count, myForm);
addRow(222, 'two', 2, ++count, myForm);
addRow(333, 'three', 3, ++count, myForm);
addRow(444, 'four', 4, ++count, myForm);
</script>
```

PHP part looks almost OK:

```
$post_number = $_POST['number'];
$post_name = $_POST['name'];
$post_price = $_POST['price'];

//check, if needed set session variables here, then
$ses_id = session_id();

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$query= "INSERT INTO products(session_id, number, name, price) VALUES (:session_id, :number, :name, :price)";

foreach($_POST['number'] as $i => $item) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $exec = $stmt->execute(array(
        ':session_id' => $ses_id,
        ':number' => $post_number[$i],
        ':name' => $post_name[$i],
        ':price' => $post_price[$i]
    ));
    if($exec == false)
        header('Location: ../error.php');
        //or print out what happened
        //$e = $stmt->errorInfo();
        //print_r($e);
        //die();
}
```